# Usage of "solch*" as an introductory word to subordinate clause

Tags: pronoun, subordinate-clause

Can the *pronoun* "solch*" (not as an adjective) be used to introduce a subordinate clause describing certain characteristics?

For example:

> - Diese Menschen sind solche, die ich nicht gern treffe.
> - Ich betrachte dieses Problem als solches, das niemand lösen kann.

Are these sentences grammatically correct? If they are, are they stylistically nice or are there better alternatives?

Comment: Good question. But, is *solche* really a subjejct in the first example?

Comment: @c.p. It's the subject of the main clause, which is more important for the sake of the diversity of the demonstration. I think it doesn't really matter what the syntactical role in the subordinate clause would be. But you are right, it's confusing, so I'll remove this altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Solche* is a demonstrative pronoun. You could it replace it with *der, die, das, einer, eine, eines* in their demonstrative pronoun use.

Both sentences are grammatically correct. Both are not best style because it's *another* demonstrative pronoun which should be used.

> Diese Menschen sind **welche**, die ich nicht gern treffe.
>
> Ich betrachte dieses Problem als **eines**, das niemand lösen kann.

BUT

> Störer! Diese Menschen sind **solche**, die anderen aber auch.
>
> Es gibt unlösbare Aufgaben. Ich betrachte dieses Problem **als solche.**

So, while *welche* is a forward-reference and demands an explanation, *solche* is a backwards-reference to something which has already been explained in a sentence before. *Der, die, das, einer, eine, eines* are neutral in that quality.

Comment: Can "welches" be used in the case of the second sentence as will?

Comment: You mean *Ich betrachte dieses Problem als eins, **welches** niemand lösen kann.* Yes, but *welches* is used as a relative pronoun here. As with der, die, das, the same word can have different functions in a sentence. (Note the dropped **e** in *eines*. If you put in the *e*, it sounds stilted because of the following *welches*, which has another *e*. That's considered as bad rhyming and avoided by German speakers. May be done by purpose, though.)

Comment: I actually meant analogically _Ich betrachte dieses Problem als **welches**, das niemand lösen kann._

Comment: No, that sounds very odd. But the plural *Ich betrachte diese Probleme als welche, die niemand lösen kann.* is widespread. That's because *welche* is considered the plural of *eines* in its demonstrative use by many many German speakers.